# how to create custom validators in Angular 2 ES5?

Tags: validation, angular

I'm trying to create a custom validator for Angular 2 using ES5. I can't find a sample online, and the cheatsheet of the documentation doesn't help and it's not documented for ES5 at all. Also, I can't transpile completely from given examples of TypeScript to ES5. Let's say the validator is a simple code validator that more than a simple Regular Expression match, should check for CRC too. Thus it can't be accomplished with built-in pattern validator of Angular 2.
Here's my code that I've tried:

```
var securityCode = ng.core.Directive({
            selector: '[securityCode][ngModel]',
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: ng.forms.NG_VALIDATORS, 
                    useExisting: securityCode, 
                    multi: true 
                }
            ]
        }).Class({
            constructor: function() {
                console.log('securityCode');
            },
            validate: function(value){
                console.log('validate...');
            },
            validator: function(value){
                console.log('validator...');
            }
        });
```

and here's how I want to use it:

```
<input mdInput type="text" requried securityCode />
```

I'm stuck now, I can't go further as this doesn't work because I get **Cannot read property 'validate' of undefined** exception, and I have no idea what to do next.